# Getting a net::ERR_ABORTED error with Tumblr API

Tags: jquery, tumblr

**What I'm trying to do:**
print the JSON response from the API in a local HTML file.

I have started jquery and ajax just now so do not know much about it :(

**Here is my code:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">    
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/myblog.tumblr.com/info?api-key=my_api_key",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(results){
            $("body").append($("<pre/>").text(JSON.stringify(results, null, "    ")));
        }
    });
    </script>
    <title>

    </title>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>

</html>
```

The complete error message is: 
jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 GET https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/myblog.tumblr.com/info?api-key=my_api_key&callback=jQuery3310981307830164331_1519323870125&_=1519323870126 net::ERR_ABORTED
I'm assuming it is a jQuery related error?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a while ago, and i fixed it by using another source code.
Try using.

Hope it works because it worked for me.

/Malling